# REST.Client.TDownloadURL don`t work with HTTPS?

Tags: rest, delphi, https

I want to use `REST.Client.TDownloadURL` to download files.

I find that it uses `System.Net.HttpClient`, and in this code I see:

```
class function THTTPClient.Create: THTTPClient;
begin
  Result := THTTPClient(TURLSchemes.GetURLClientInstance('HTTP')); // do not translate
end;
```

I think `REST.Client.TDownloadURL` works only with HTTP and not HTTPS, is that right?

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324989/tdownloadurl-cannot-download-from-https) talks about `Vcl.ExtActns.TDownloadURL` instead, which uses Microsoft's `URLDownloadToFile()` function.  Does `REST.Client.TDownloadURL` use `URLDownloadToFile()`, too?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TDownloadURL cannot download from HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14324989/tdownloadurl-cannot-download-from-https)

Answer (score 0):

I`ve investigated the question.
REST.Client.TDownloadURL work using TWinHTTPClient which provide Client Certificate if it needed.